# Exclude Current and Sticky Post

Tags: sticky-post

On a single Post page I have a side bar displaying up to three other, related posts. How can I exclude both Sticky Posts and the Current post?

I know how to exclude the Current post and how to exclude Sticky Posts by using post_not_in in a WP_Query, see code example below. But I guess you can not use post_not_in twice in the same query. Any suggestions?

```
$current_post_ID = get_the_ID();

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' )
            'post__not_in' => array($current_post_ID)
        );
```

Comment: Have you tried joining the IDs together in a single array, which you can pas to `post__not_in`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever an array of arguments is a function parameter in a WP core function it is parsed via [`wp_parse_args`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_parse_args) and almost always [extracted](http://php.net/extract) into single variables.
I.e. *no, you cannot use the same argument twice*.

What you want to do is something like this:

```
$exclude = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$exclude[] = get_the_ID();

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post__not_in' => $exclude
);
```

As an aside, you were also missing a comma.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the current post's ID to the array of IDs of your sticky posts, and pass this single array to `post__not_in`:

```
$current_post_ID = get_the_ID();

$excluded_ids = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$excluded_ids[] = $current_post_ID;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post__not_in' => $excluded_ids
);
```

Also note that you didn't type a comma after your first `post__not_in`. That might cause problems as the second instance of `post__not_in` isn't recognized as another element of the array.

Comment: [`get_option( 'sticky_posts' )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts) returns an array, not a string. Ain't no need to explode anything.

Comment: Then `$excluded_ids = get_option( 'sticky_posts' ); $excluded_ids[] = $current_post_ID;` would do.

Comment: Indeed it does, @Marc.